# Is there a method to find out if a package is to be installed with distutils instead of setuptools?

Tags: python, distutils, distribute

I can look inside setup.py I suppose to see if it's a distutils package.  But in the process of familiarizing myself with python package management I have noticed that there seems to be more than one way to do it.  So:

How can I check an unzipped packages directory or setup.py to see how to build it?

EDIT: When I say 'build' I mean is it going to use distutils or setuptools, or distribute.  I am using buildout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to know? What's wrong with just running

```
/path/to/your/python setup.py install
```

?

Comment: Well I'd like to use buildout.  I'd like to pick a recipe based on what I need.

Comment: Consider editing your question to explain what your needs/wants/likes are. "I'd like to pick a recipe based on what I need" is a bit vague.

Comment: Ok. There is no uninstall in python packaging at this point. I agree, if I could uninstall like I could with apt, then your solution would work, although the actual question was about finding information. Not a big deal, I can just do what I do now and look in setup.py.  I was wondering if there was a different, way.

Comment: Not true :)  You can have a semi-manual uninstall with distutils/setuptools if you use the --record option of the install command, and you can have automated uninstall with pip or distutils2.